# How to restrict authentication to a specific domain using IdentityServer4

Tags: security, asp.net-core, google-oauth, identityserver4

In the context of using IdentityServer4 to secure an ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 client and associated API, **how do I enforce domain-specific authentication restrictions?**

---

I have worked through the IdentityServer [quickstarts](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html) and have a working MVC client talking to a IdentityServer instance (apologies if using the wrong terminology). I am using External Authentication (Google) and do not have anything mildly complicated such as local logins / database etc. I am *not* using ASP.NET Identity. This is all working just fine.

**Problem**: I need to only allows users from a certain company into the application. To achieve this I will examine either their email address or [the 'hd' claim from Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo) to examine their domain and match it to a whitelist.

1. Do I implement this in the Client or the IdentityServer?
2. Can anyone point me to an example of where this has been done or provide an explanation on how to implement it?

Happy to post code of current implementation if of use, only reason I haven't is that it is the same as the quickstarts linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this logic belongs to your IdentityServer instance.

But it may exists on your application/client only if the email's domain check is required only for a single application. In this way, you may have action filter to check the claim, and you need to add `hd` to user claim list.

The logic of checking with the whitelist should staty on IdentityServer. You can set a flag on client to check whether system need to validate the email domain or not

Comment: Thanks MJK - any chance you have a sample or know of one I can take a squizz at?